# REPLACE in Sql replaces more than once issue

Tags: sql

Weird not sure if I have it correct but the output is weird:

```
 select * 
   into #TempScormModuelsTable  
 from Scorm.ScormModules

 select * from #TempScormModuelsTable 
 DECLARE @ScormModuleId int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT ScormModuleId from #TempScormModuelsTable

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ScormModuleId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

   update #TempScormModuelsTable  
   set Directory = REPLACE(Directory,'SCORM','ScormPackages'),
   RelativeHtmlPath = REPLACE(RelativeHtmlPath,'SCORM','ScormPackages')

     FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ScormModuleId
  END  

--drop table #TempScormModuelsTable 

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

then in the column Directory I have this! 
    E:\inetpub\www.sellandprosper.com\ScormPackagesPackagesPackagesPackagesPackagesPackagesPackagesPackages\SellingOfficeWithNewPCs

"ScormPackagesPackagesPackagesPackagesPackagesPackagesPackagesPackages" was "SCORM" and I just want it as ScormPackages..yikes

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not SQL.

You need something closer to...

```
UPDATE
  Scorm.ScormModules_backup
SET
  Directory        = REPLACE(Directory,        'SCORM', 'ScormPackages'),
  RelativeHtmlPath = REPLACE(RelativeHtmlPath, 'SCORM', 'ScormPackages')
```

SQL is already set based and this will naturally apply this to every row *(much like your FOREACH pseudocode)*.

I'm not sure what your `WHERE` clause is meant to do, but you can append `WHERE` clauses to `UPDATE`s too.

**EDIT**

Okay you just totally changed the code in your question.

Now, you're looking in a cursor, but the update is being done to the whole table.

So, if you have 8 rows, you do the update 8 times.  But each time you do it to every row in the table.

Comment: Thanks! i edited my OP though to use a cursor or will above go though all the rows in the table?